# WebGL m3 object?

Tags: webgl

thanks to list for WebGL `vec4()` help!  It was fast; don't know if a Google search (Swizzling) would have worked, but maybe?

Another WebGL question; then I should have resources from list to help me in future WebGL q's.
I guess a good WebGL book would have answered this; although I am reading WebGL Programming Guide by Matsuda and Lea.  I am 61 years old and books are how I learned in the past but guess that online is the way now.

I don't know what m3 is in the following WebGL statement:

```js
matrix = m3.translate(matrix,translation[0],translation[1]);
```

I know there are Matrix definitions and `Matrix4` objects but no help here.

Again, thank you.

Comment: I'd recommend [these articles](https://webglfundamentals.org) as a supplement to your book. They derive their own math library.

Comment: @gman these articles are very valuable too! I've build my WebGL course on this book and these articles. It's a great approach to start from the program's "gl_Position = doMathToMakeClipspaceCoordinates" to demistify shaders

Answer (score 1):

This book you quote is gold to learn WebGL in the right way! Glad we can help here too (*By the way, please remember to accept the best answer here*
)

m3 is an instance of Matrix4 type you can find in cuon-matrix.js. Every example in the book uses this file for the maths part.

```
matrix = m3.translate(matrix,translation[0],translation[1]);
```

The translate function actually applies a translation on 3 axis to the matrix instance (m3 in your case)

```
Matrix4.prototype.translate = function(x, y, z)
```

Thus the line of code you ask for is wrong. You should not pass matrix as first parameter. There are only 3 params: the translation amount on x, y and z axis.

Comment: THANK YOU.  The help from this list is invaluable :-)

Comment: Good if it helps you (and please remember to accept the best answer on your questions)